# full text search postgresql : how to substitute 2 letters

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql database with entries in latin. The letters "u" and "v" can in any text and at any moment be substituted for each other.

So, the word "individue", can also be written "indiuidue" or "indiuidve".

How do I instruct the query (or format the database) so that a search on "individue" also returns the 2 other possibilities?

Thanks,

Comment: If you really want to do this in a generalizable way, you need to create your own [FTS dictionary](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html). If you need to do it for a limited amount of words, a `synonyms` dictionary could do the work. Otherwise, you need to create a custom dicionary. I'd start from the [source code of `unaccent`](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/unaccent_8c_source.html).

Comment: On second thought: probably using `unaccent` with the appropriate rules can do the job for you (you'll not be removing accents, but changing v -> u)

Comment: Does that mean I should create a file `/usr/local/var/postgres/tsearch_data/latin.rules`  that contains a first line `u v` and a second line `v u ` ?

Comment: Easier solution: upon the entry of data into the database, gsub all v and V into u and U.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways-- you could create a custom parser for FTS, or you could
simply do something like:

```
create index on base_table 
    using gin( (to_tsvector(replace(upper(column_to_search),'U','V')))
```

And remember to do the same replace(search_criteria),'U','V') on all searches

Of course you can turn this into a immutable function that will always convert the U's to V's.. and just call that in both places (the index and when searching). That way, you won't have to write out that ugly replace so often...

Comment: Thanks, I did this, but in a ruby methods, which also has the advantage of modernising the latin spelling (which evolved over time and which currently doesn't have the letters "v" and "j"). So before inserting data into DB I do `.gsub(/[vV]/,'v' => 'u', 'V' => 'U')` and likewise when searching.

Comment: As long as you're OK with the actual data changing. The indexing method has the benefit of having both the original version and the substituted version. If you don't need the original, then replacing before inserting is definitely easier.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use the "select ... similar to ..." as in:

```
> createdb test
> psql -d test
psql (9.4.9)
Type "help" for help.

test=# create table mytest(thestring varchar(20));
CREATE TABLE

test=# insert into mytest values('individue');
INSERT 0 1
test=# insert into mytest values('indiuidue');
INSERT 0 1
test=# insert into mytest values('indiuidve');
INSERT 0 1
test=# insert into mytest values('indiuidde');
INSERT 0 1
test=# insert into mytest values('indiiidde');
INSERT 0 1

test=# select * from mytest
test-# ;
 thestring 
-----------
 individue
 indiuidue
 indiuidve
 indiuidde
 indiiidde
(5 rows)

test=# select * from mytest where thestring similar to '%(u|v)%';
 thestring 
-----------
 individue
 indiuidue
 indiuidve
 indiuidde
(4 rows)
```

If this does not suit your purposes then regular expressions would be able to handle a more complex situation.

Comment: that would lead to a query like `select id, document_number, document_date from document where entire_text SIMILAR TO  '%indi(u|v)id(u|v)%'; ` I can't do that on all words for the entire database, I'm afraid...